# Configuring authorization for activemq

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I'm writing a test application using `ActiveMQ embedded broker` on the same machine. I tried to configure it as follows:

`activemq.xml`:

```
<amq:broker  useJmx="false" persistent="false">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
      <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>

<amq:simpleAuthenticationPlugin >
    <amq:users>
        <amq:authenticationUser username="system" password="manager"
          groups="users,admins" />
    </amq:users>
</amq:simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
```

Tomcat's `context.xml`: !!The Password is deliberately incorrect!!

```
<Resource name="jms/ConnectionFactory" auth="Container" userName="userssname" password="passwords"
    type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" description="JMS Connection Factory"
    factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"
    brokerName="LocalActiveMQBroker" />
```

But, when I try to perform injection I can easily create a `ConnectionFactory` object and send/receive messages even with incorrect password. How can I deny this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you need to add authorization entries for queues and topics as well.

Example authorization plugin configuration:

```
<authorizationPlugin>
    <map>
        <authorizationMap>
            <authorizationEntries>
                <authorizationEntry queue=">" write="admins,publishers" read="admins,consumers" admin="admins" />
                <authorizationEntry topic=">" write="admins,publishers" read="admins,consumers" admin="admins" />
                <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="everyone" write="everyone" admin="everyone"/>
            </authorizationEntries>
        </authorizationMap>
    </map>
</authorizationPlugin>
```